# How to retrieve the comment of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I recently discovered you can [attach a comment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) to all sort of objects in PostgreSQL.  In particular, I'm interested on playing with the comment of a database.  For example, to **set** the comment of a database:

```
COMMENT ON DATABASE mydatabase IS 'DB Comment';
```

However, what is the opposite statement, to **get** the comment of `mydatabase`?

From the `psql` command line, I can see the comment along with other information as a result of the `\l+` command; which I could use with the aid of awk in order to achieve my goal.  But I'd rather use an SQL statement, if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the comment on the database, use the following query:

```
select description from pg_shdescription
join pg_database on objoid = pg_database.oid
where datname = '<database name>'
```

This query will get you table comment for the given table name:

```
select description from pg_description
join pg_class on pg_description.objoid = pg_class.oid
where relname = '<your table name>'
```

If you use the same table name in different schemas, you need to modify it a bit:

```
select description from pg_description
join pg_class on pg_description.objoid = pg_class.oid
join pg_namespace on pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
where relname = '<table name>' and nspname='<schema name>'
```

Comment: Weird that the comment isn't available in `information_schema`. It should be, since `pg_catalog` structure isn't guaranteed to be stable from major release to major release.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The dedicated functions I describe in my answer will keep working in any case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Great, that's a much better option - much safer.

Comment: **for column comments** one has to utilize the `pg_description.objsubid`: `select c.table_name, c.column_name, c.ordinal_position, d.objsubid, d.description  from pg_description d  join information_schema.columns c on ( c.table_schema = current_schema  and  current_schema||'.'||c.table_name)::regclass = d.objoid  and  c.ordinal_position = d.objsubid )`

Comment: One can use `current_database()` in place of `'<database name>'` for the currently connected database.

Answer (score 45):

First off, your query for table comments can be simplified using a cast to the appropriate [**object identifier type**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html):

```
SELECT description
FROM   pg_description
WHERE  objoid = 'myschema.mytbl'::regclass;
```

The schema part is optional. If you omit it, your current [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) decides visibility of any table named `mytbl`.

**Better yet**, there are **dedicated functions** in PostgreSQL to simplify and canonize these queries. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE):

> `obj_description(`*`object_oid`*, *`catalog_name`*`)` ... get comment for a
>   database object
>
> `shobj_description(`*`object_oid`*, *`catalog_name`*`)` ... get comment for a shared database object

Description for table:

```
SELECT obj_description('myschema.mytbl'::regclass, 'pg_class');
```

Description for database:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.shobj_description(d.oid, 'pg_database') AS "Description"
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE  datname = 'mydb';
```

#### How do you find out about that?

Well, reading the excellent manual is enlightening. :)
But there is a more direct route in this case: most `psql` meta commands are implemented with  plain SQL. Start a session with `psql -E`, to see the magic behind the curtains. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

> `-E`
>   `--echo-hidden`
>
> Echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands. You can use this to study psql's internal operations. This
>   is equivalent to setting the variable `ECHO_HIDDEN` to `on`.

Comment: I didn't know about `psql -E`, probably due to reading the psql man page too quickly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This query will get only table comment for all tables

```
SELECT RelName,Description 
FROM pg_Description
JOIN pg_Class 
ON pg_Description.ObjOID = pg_Class.OID
WHERE ObjSubID = 0
```

Comment: How to select ALL tables regardless they have comments or not; meaning both with and without comments in given schema?

Answer (score 1):

For tables, try

```
\dd TABLENAME
```

This shows the comment I added to a table

Comment: For functions, inside a `psql` session, one can do `\df+ func_name` to get the description too.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the comment of a table

```
 SELECT obj_description('public.myTable'::regclass)
 FROM pg_class
 WHERE relkind = 'r' limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the comments on all the databases (not on their objects like tables etc.) :

```sql
SELECT datname, shobj_description( oid, 'pg_database' ) AS comment
FROM pg_database
ORDER BY datname
```

An example showing databases, sizes and descriptions from a shell script:

```sh
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT datname,
 format('%8s MB.', pg_database_size(datname)/1000000) AS size,
 shobj_description( oid, 'pg_database' ) as comment
 FROM pg_database ORDER BY datname"
```

Sample output:

```
       datname        |     size     |                       comment                       
----------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 last_wikidb          |       18 MB. | Wiki backup from yesterday
 postgres             |        7 MB. | default administrative connection database
 previous_wikidb      |       18 MB. | Wiki backup from the day before yesterday
 some_db              |       82 MB. | 
 template0            |        7 MB. | unmodifiable empty database
 template1            |        7 MB. | default template for new databases
```