# Any way to generate a postgres-comment using a select-statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, comments

Is there any way to generate the text for comments by using a select statement (or otherwise to generate it dynamically)?

Background:

I have a rather big query stored in a table table_a for reusing it. In the comment for the table I've stored the creation date (and thus the date of the data status). This date I generate using the capabilities of DbVisualizer (DbVisualizer-Variables)::

```
comment on table table_a is 'Date: ${dbvis-date}$'
```

Now I use this table_a to calculate something and store it in a  table table_b.

I now would like to put the comment of table_a as the comment of table_b. 
The comment can be obtained as described in [How to retrieve the comment of a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493978/how-to-retrieve-the-comment-of-a-postgresql-database):

```
select description from pg_description
join pg_class on pg_description.objoid = pg_class.oid
where relname = 'table_a'
```

So, if I could use a select-statement in `comment`, it would be an easy thing to do - but appearently it is not allowed...

```
--doesn't work
comment on 'table_b' is (select description from pg_description
join pg_class on pg_description.objoid = pg_class.oid
where relname = 'table_a')
```

I use Postgresql 9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE` inside an [anonymous block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO 
$$
  DECLARE
    comment_text text;
  BEGIN
    comment_text := (
      select description 
      from pg_description 
      join pg_class on pg_description.objoid = pg_class.oid 
      where relname = 'table_a');

    EXECUTE('COMMENT ON TABLE table_b IS ''' || comment_text || '''');
  END;
$$;
```