# How To Retrieve PostgreSQL schema comments

Tags: postgresql

I would like to version control PostgreSQL schemas with the `COMMENT ON` syntax (whether that's a good practice is another question) but I'm not sure how to retrieve these comments later on.

There's quite some writing around how to retrieve database and column comments, not so much about schemas.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493978/how-to-retrieve-the-comment-of-a-postgresql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve Schema comments, you can use psql utility. The comments can be viewed with `\dn+` in the prompt. Comments are stored in the Description Column.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT obj_description('public'::regnamespace, 'pg_namespace');
```