# How do I get a schema comment in Postgresql using a query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a script that's supposed to dump SQL object definitions in a certain format, and I'm looking for a way to get the schema comment programmatically.

What SQL query do I need to run if I know what the schema's name is?

I'm currently on PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the comment of a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493978/how-to-retrieve-the-comment-of-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, because it shows how to get the comment for a table or a database. I tried to modify the queries in that answer to get a schema comment, but without success.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes we're working on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `obj_description()` for that:

```
comment on schema some_schema is 'Some comment';
select obj_description('some_schema'::regnamespace);
```

Or to get it from all schemas:

```
select nspname, obj_description(oid, 'pg_namespace')
from pg_namespace;
```

Comment: The second one worked for me, the first one doesn't run because it doesn't know what `regnamespace` is.

Comment: @Primordial_Hamster: that's because you are using an outdated Postgres version. It works with all supported Postgres versions.